# dplyr group by multiple variables summarise by multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, tidyverse

New to R.
Using dplyr, trying to group_by multiple variables, summarize by multiple variables, multiple functions.

This works as expected

```
mtcars %>% 
+     group_by(cyl,hp) %>% 
+     summarise(min_mpg = min(mpg) , min_disp = min(disp), max_mpg = max(mpg) , max_disp = max(disp))
```

But when I try to replicate with my df

```
vmp %>% 
    +     group_by(Priority,LOS) %>% 
    +     summarise(inv_total = sum(Inv_Total), sr_count = count(SR_Nmbr))
```

I receive this error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: no
>   applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "factor".

What am I doing wrong?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
vmp %>%
     mutate(Inv_Total=as.numeric(as.character(Inv_Total))) %>% 
     group_by(Priority,LOS) %>%
     summarise(sr_count=n(), 
               inv_total=sum(Inv_Total))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `type.convert` to convert the column types automatically

```
vmp %>%
    mutate_all(funs(type.convert(as.character(.), as.is = TRUE))) %>%
    group_by(Priority, LOS) %>%
    summarise(inv_total = sum(Inv_Total), sr_count =n())
```